# Make a group by with a where in statement Laravel

Tags: laravel, select

I am writing a little script to load an Attendee_logs, based that counts the total of prints for based on the hour.

First I load the id's from the attendees

```
$allAttendees->pluck('id')->implode(',')
```

So I get 389832, 321321 from this (this are the id's from the attendees, based on a group).

Now I want to group them by the hour.
But I cannot find out how I add the `whereIn` statement

```
$badgesPrintedByDate = DB::table('Attendee_logs')->select(DB::raw('hour(created_at)'), DB::raw('COUNT(id)'))->whereIn('id', [$allAttendees->pluck('id')->implode(',')])->groupBy(DB::raw('hour(created_at)'));
```

When I do it like this, I get an empty result.
But when I remove the whereIn I get a result.

So my question, How can I count the rows based on the Hour and where I also give the ID's with it :)?

Comment: Because the code you compile for whereIn will look like this `['389832,321321']` instead of `['389832','321321']` or `[389832,321321]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is gonna work:

```
$badgesPrintedByDate = DB::table('Attendee_logs')->select(DB::raw('hour(created_at)'), DB::raw('COUNT(id)'))->whereIn('id', $allAttendees->pluck('id')->all())->groupBy(DB::raw('hour(created_at)'));
```

Instead of saying:

```
$allAttendees->pluck('id')->all()
```

Which returns an array of ids, you can also say:'

```
$allAttendees->pluck('id')->values()
```

Or:

```
$allAttendees->pluck('id')->toArray();
```